# How to apply list of regex pattern on list

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of strings and a list of patterns
like:

```
links <- c(
"http://www.google.com"
,"google.com"
,"www.google.com"
,"http://google.com"
,"http://google.com/"
,"www.google.com/#"
,"www.google.com/xpto"
,"http://google.com/xpto"
,"http://google.com/xpto&utml"
,"www.google.com/gclid=102938120391820391+ajdakjsdsjkajasn_JAJSDSJA")

patterns <- c(".com$","/$")
```

what i want is wipe out all links that matches this patterns.
and get this result:

```
"www.google.com/#"
"www.google.com/xpto"
"http://google.com/xpto"
"http://google.com/xpto&utml"
"www.google.com/gclid=102938120391820391+ajdakjsdsjkajasn_JAJSDSJA"
```

if i use

```
x<-lapply (patterns, grepl, links)
```

i get

```
[[1]]
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[2]]
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

what takes me to this 2 lists

```
> links[!x[[2]]]
[1] "http://www.google.com"                                             "google.com"                                                       
[3] "www.google.com"                                                    "http://google.com"                                                
[5] "www.google.com/#"                                                  "www.google.com/xpto"                                              
[7] "http://google.com/xpto"                                            "http://google.com/xpto&utml"                                      
[9] "www.google.com/gclid=102938120391820391+ajdakjsdsjkajasn_JAJSDSJA"


> links[!x[[1]]]
[1] "http://google.com/"                                                "www.google.com/#"                                                 
[3] "www.google.com/xpto"                                               "http://google.com/xpto"                                           
[5] "http://google.com/xpto&utml"                                       "www.google.com/gclid=102938120391820391+ajdakjsdsjkajasn_JAJSDSJA"
```

in this case each result list wiped 1 pattern out.. but i wanted 1 list with all patterns wiped... how to apply the regex to only one result ... or somehow to merge the  n boolean vectors always choosing  true.
like:

```
b[1] <- c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
b[2] <- c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)
b[3] <- c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)

res <- somefunction(b)
res 
TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know at all how the R language works. But would one single regular expression help? If it's the case, you could replace the 2 regexes with this one: `(\.com|/)$` where `(abc|xyz)` means "find abc or xyz". You also have to escape the `.` as it means "any character".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases the best solution will be to merge the regular expression patterns, and to apply a single pattern search,  [as shown in Thomas’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60060025/1968).

However, it is also trivial to merge logical vectors by combining them with logical operations. In your case, you want to compute the member-wise [logical disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction). Between two vectors, this can be computed as `x | y`. Between a list of multiple vectors, it can be computed using [`Reduce(`|`, logical_list)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html).

In your case, this results in:

```
any_matching = Reduce(`|`, lapply(patterns, grepl, links))
result = links[! any_matching]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
links[!sapply("(\\.com|/)$", grepl, links)]
```

Explanation:

You can use `sapply` so you get a vector and not a list

I'd use the pattern `"(\\.com|/)$"` (i.e. ends with .com OR /).

In the end I negate the resulting boolean vector using `!`.

Comment: wouldn't `links[which(!grepl(".com$|/$",links))]` work as well? Why do you need the apply?

Comment: It does. But Apply is used to work vector wise, usually is way faster and cleaner

Comment: @GonzaloFallouxCosta Faster and cleaner than what? On the contrary, it’s probably faster to match once against a combined pattern than to repeatedly match against sub-patterns. But in this particular case the `sapply` in this answer is completely redundant, it serves no purpose whatsoever And `sapply` has its own issues (using `vapply` would be better but is also redundant here). In sum, this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the base R code below, using `grep`

```
r <- grep(paste0(patterns,collapse = "|"),links,value = TRUE,invert = TRUE)
```

such that

```
> r
[1] "www.google.com/#"                                                 
[2] "www.google.com/xpto"                                              
[3] "http://google.com/xpto"                                           
[4] "http://google.com/xpto&utml"                                      
[5] "www.google.com/gclid=102938120391820391+ajdakjsdsjkajasn_JAJSDSJA"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `stringr::str_subset()` function.

```
library(stringr)

str_subset(links, pattern = ".com$|/$", negate = TRUE)
```

Comment: Two down votes to my answer and nobody explain why. I know I did not include a detailed answer, but it is a useful way to get the job done.

Comment: me neither
 it worked   i  just had to use past0 to get  ".com$|/$"